# How to add a new item to the list?(java)

Tags: java

So i can get access to the list with a getter but how do i add a new user to the list ? What i need to add ?

```
private List<User> userList= new ArrayList<User>(){{
    add(new User("ABC","123","B","b"));
    add(new User("CBA","123","I","b"));
}}; 

public List<User> getUserList() {
    return userList;
}
```

Yes i have added 2 users but they are added when i create the list, I wan'ted to have some kind of a method that i can call and it adds a new user to the list. Something like

```
    public void addNewUser(User){
    //some kind of code
    }
```

Comment: you already seem capable of adding new users to your list, what exactly do you mean ?

Comment: So you know double-braces initialization, and you don't know how to add a new User to the list?

Comment: Did you even make any attempt at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have added two users here already by using a double brace [initialisation block](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?DoubleBraceInitialization). To add outside of the initialisation block simply run

```
userList.add(new User("XYZ","42","D","d"));
```

Or if you have not got access to userlist then

```
public void addToList(User u) {
    userList.add(u);
}
```

This second way with the add method follows [this pattern](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?TellDontAsk) (tell dont ask)

Comment: thx a lot this worked for me 

public void addToList(User u) {
    userList.add(u);
}

Answer (score 1):

```
getUserList().add(new User("DEF","456","E","e"));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public void setUser(String s1, String s2, String s3, String s4) {
User u = new User(s1,s2,s3,s4);
getUserList.add(u);
}
```

Comment: Better to add a little explaination